# Completion of Metric Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I am trying to show that if $(M,d)$ is a metric space, then if $C$ is the set of all Cauchy sequences on M and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $C$ given by $(x_n) \sim (y_n)$ iff $\lim d(x_n, y_n)=0.$ Then the set $C/{\sim}$ is complete with the metric $d'(X,Y)= \lim d(X_n, Y_n)$ is complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: First you have to show that $d'$ is well-defined on $C/\sim.$ Not hard to do, but a necessary step. You will need that $\mathbb R$ is complete.

Comment: This is a standard result found in many textbooks. It would help if you could tell us what you have tried: Did you not understand one of the textbook proofs? Did you try to start this problem by yourself? If so, how did you start this problem, what ideas did you have, where did you get stuck? See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for hints on how to improve your question, in particular see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).